# Angular 2 Routing, .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, angular, routes, angular2-routing

I am having some problems with my routeing. It works fine on localhost but when I put it on the server and do a refresh of the page I get a 404 Error.

So I made an `.htaccess` file and put it in the same place as my `index.html`:

```
RewriteEngine On
# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

But it is still not working what am I doing wrong?
Do I have to add something to my Angular routeing?
Can someone help?

Comment: "put it in the same place as my index.html" - Where exactly is "the same place"? A subdirectory? Document root?

Comment: Hang on... did you only implement this `.htaccess` file in order to try to solve your 404 error? Did you not have a `.htaccess` file on your `localhost`?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^ /index.html
> ```

Try removing the slash prefix on the `RewriteRule` *substitution*. For example:

```
 RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```

This is now relative to the current directory (where the `index.html` file is located), rather than the document root.

---

> ```
> # If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
> RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
> RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
> RewriteRule ^ - [L]
> ```

Note the cause of your problem, but `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}` is the same as `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}`, so it is more common to see this written as:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

However, it would be more efficient to prefix this with a check for file extensions of known assets to avoid having to check every request to see if it is a file or a directory (which is relatively expensive). For example:

```
# Allow any request for CSS, JS and images straight through...
RewriteRule .\.(css|js|jpe?g|png|gif) - [L]
```

Comment: I will try this @w3dk but are there other thinks that i also need to do? do I need to add something else also?

Comment: I don't know if there is "something else" you need to do. But you said it was working OK on localhost, but not on the server and presented your `.htaccess`. The thing I mentioned above is one thing that _could_ prevent this working on the live server. You've not answered my query above... where is this `.htaccess` file?

Comment: I use Heroku now to host my application my .htaccess file is now in the same map as the index and that is the map template/freemarker